# Torque and acceleration curve?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to have some more acceleration control over my wheel, which is just a cylinder that gets torque added.

```
wheel.AddTorque(wheel.transform.up * throttle);
```

What I actually want is to let it accelerate very quickly but at a give speed this the acceleration should quickly fall off. Like curve that starts very steep. Is there any way I can influence this using the basic `.Addtorque`?

Currently, my wheel just accelerates quickly to maximum velocity. Adding drag to it slows it down but I don't have the desired control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just affect the `angularVelocity` property of the `rigidbody` *directly*. Just as you can affect the `velocity` property instead of using the `.AddForce` method.

### Try this pseudo code

```
public float topSpeed;
public float decelRate;
protected bool slowDown = false;
public void Update()
{
    float speed = wheel.angularVelocity.magnitude;
    if (speed >= topSpeed) slowDown = true;
    if (slowDown)
    {
        speed -= decelRate * Time.deltaTime;
        wheel.angularVelocity = wheel.angularVelocity.normalized * speed;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `magnitude` calls are expensive, due to a square root function inside, though in this case i didn't see another way around it so you should be fine. Also i am *not* slowing it down in a set direction which is important, because this way it will slow down no matter what direction it is rotating in, or what way it is orientated.